# Height specified is not the real one on extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2, gridpanel

Hi guys i need help with grid panel, I set the height of the grid to 200px and when I see the grid on the browser it has 600px. I tried to force height with setHeight(), but didn't work.

The code for the grid panel is the next:

```
for(var i=0; i<json.length;++i){
    var data = JSON.parse(json[i].json);

    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        fields: ['question', 'type', 'answer'],
        data: data.questions
    });

    var rEditor = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {
            clicksToEdit: 2,
            listeners:{
                edit: function (editor, e) { }
            }
    });

    var itemId ="";
    if(json[i].enabled){
        act++;
        itemId = 'active'+act;
    }else{
        inact++
        itemId = 'inactive'+inact;
    }

    var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        height: 200,
        margin: '20 35 0 35',
        title: 'Group of Questions',
        store: store,
        plugins: [rEditor],
        itemId: itemId,
        stateId: itemId,
        columns: [
            {xtype: 'rownumberer', stateId: itemId+'_1', width:30},
            { text: 'Question', dataIndex: 'question', stateId: itemId+'_2', tdCls: 'gridTree', flex: 1, editor: {xtype: 'textfield'}},
            { text: 'Type', dataIndex: 'type', stateId: itemId+'_3', tdCls: 'gridTree', flex: 1, editor: {xtype: 'combobox', fieldLabel: 'Choose Type', store: types,queryMode: 'local', valueField: 'name',tpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate','<tpl for=".">','<div class="x-boundlist-item">{name}</div>','</tpl>'), displayTpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate','<tpl for=".">','{name}','</tpl>')}},
            { text: 'Answer', dataIndex: 'answer', stateId: itemId+'_4', tdCls: 'gridTree', flex: 1, editor: {xtype: 'textfield', store: types, }}
        ],
        dockedItems: [
            {
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                dock: 'top',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        scale: 'medium',
                        glyph: Rd.config.icnLight,
                        listeners: {
                            click: {
                                fn: function(){
                                    Ext.Ajax.request({
                                        url: '',
                                        method: 'POST',
                                        params: {
                                            country: country,
                                            language: language,
                                            realm_id: realm_id,
                                        },
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                ]
            }
        ],
    });

    if(json[i].enabled){
        active.add(grid);
        actives.push(grid);
    }else{
        inactive.add(grid);
        inactives.push(grid);
    }
}
```

I forget to say that in the same container i can have more than one grid panel. I don't know if this is possible. Can you guys tell me please.

Comment: Check the layout of `active`. If the layout is `fit` or a `hbox` with `align:'stretch'`, the grid height is ignored because the layout says that it wants to render only one.

Comment: @Alexander that worked i had the panel active and inactive with layout fit. Thanks for the answer